# SharePoint Document Library - get filename and then use that file path to read the file in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a quick question around SharePoint on premises and Power BI Desktop. I have fairly extensive experience in SharePoint but just getting started with some Power BI integration. My requirement is that there is a document library that gets some CSV reports from an external source. The file names have a date and time stamp. For example a sample file path could be "/sites/testsite/Shared Documents/testfile_2020_04_22.csv"

These files are sent to the document library using an automated process. What my client wants is to be able to read the latest file published to SharePoint and then create some reports around it.

What I have tried is to use PowerBI OData feed option to query the SP Document Library as follows:

```
https://intranet.contoso.com/customreporting/_Api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$top=1&$orderby=Created desc&$select=Title,FileLeafRef
```

The above endpoint returns the latest file published. However, when I query OData Feed in PowerBI I get a 404 not found.

I, then, changed my approach a bit and decided to use Web Feed using the above URL which returns XML data but I have yet to figure out how to parse this XML. While trying to figure this out, I changed the approach again and used the ListData.svc endpoint which does seem to return data.

However, I am not sure how to pass the value of FileLeafRef to the Power BI to ensure that the reports read the latest file path that is returned.

Can someone please provide some guidance around it?

Thank you.